# Passing Route as prop from reusable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router-dom, react-proptypes

I have the following component. I want to make it reusable, so I can use it on different part of the app... with different routes..

**THE COMPONENT:**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import './styles.scss';

export class ActionHeader extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    linkTitle1: PropTypes.string,
    linkTitle2: PropTypes.string,
    linkNumber1: PropTypes.number,
    linkNumber2: PropTypes.number
  };

  render() {
    const { linkTitle1, linkTitle2, linkNumber1, linkNumber2 } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <div className="link-box">
            <h5>{linkTitle1}</h5>
            <Link to="/management/users">
              <h4>{linkNumber1}</h4>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <div className="link-box px-4">
            <h5>{linkTitle2}</h5>
            <Link to="/management/accounts">
              <h4>{linkNumber2}</h4>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h fa-lg justify-content-center" />
        </div>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  user: state.auth.user
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(ActionHeader);
```

I have 2 questions. First what kind of `PropType` I need to pass to the PropTypes. Also what else do I need to do? obviously now It works with hardcoded routes. But I need to have the dynamic and be called as a prop to the component I will use it in...

Comment: Did you faced any issue ? Can you be more clear of what dynamic ?

Comment: I want to remove the hardcoded route. And add a prop there. Then depending on whcich router the component is nested in, I want to user route there... This will be reused in a few screens... Probably will try out the answer below... and let youu know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution would be to just add two `linkHref` props and use them in your links.

```
export class ActionHeader extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    linkTitle1: PropTypes.string,
    linkTitle2: PropTypes.string,
    linkNumber1: PropTypes.number,
    linkNumber2: PropTypes.number,
    linkHref1: PropTypes.string,
    linkHref2: PropTypes.string,
  };

  ...

  <h5>{linkTitle1}</h5>
    <Link to={linkHref1}>
      <h4>{linkNumber1}</h4>
    </Link>
  </h5>
```

Comment: Ok, it seems to work, except redirection. It always redirects to the first one. Probably a problem with the router config. I will check it out and let you know..